# Solve the equation for x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rational-functions, algebraic-equations

solve the following equation for x
 $(x^2-8x-3)÷(8x-3)=(x^2+4x+4)÷(4x+4)$

The problem here I am encountering with is figuring out which method to be used here for solving.  I am not getting how to start with. 
Hope I will get good hint.

Comment: Turn this equation to a polynomial one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just "cross multiply" so to speak. Then you get a cubic equation on both sides. Combine like terms, gathering them all on the same side of the equation, and solve for $x$.

To clarify what I mean by "cross multiply:" if you have $$\frac ab = \frac cd$$"cross multiplying" means you multiply both sides by the product of denominators. This gives you $ad = bc$.